How to verify Azure Monitor Agent (AMA) is correctly installed on Azure VMs after extension deployment?
I have two Windows-based virtual machines running in Azure, and I am trying to collect Windows Event Logs using the new Azure Monitor Agent (AMA). Here's what I've done so far:
Created a Data Collection Rule (DCR) and added both VMs as resources.
Verified that the AzureMonitorWindowsAgent extension is visible under the VM extensions, and the status is "Provisioning succeeded."
AzureMonitorWindowsAgent extension installed
Connected to one of the VMs via RDP to check if the agent was installed, but I could not find any service named "Azure Monitor Agent" or anything similar. I can just find a "Windows Azure Guest Agent"
Azure Monitor Agent not installed inside the VM
My question is:
How can I verify that the Azure Monitor Agent (AMA) has been successfully installed after the extension is deployed?
Does it just take time for the service to appear, or is there another way to ensure it's properly installed and running?
I expected to find a Windows service named "Azure Monitor Agent" or something equivalent, but it’s not listed. Any guidance on troubleshooting or verifying the installation would be appreciated!


Here is the process to install the Azure  Monitor Windows Agent on a VM and retrieve the logs from it.


Install the AzureMonitorWindowsAgent extension on an Azure VM using PowerShell.

Set-AzVMExtension -Name AzureMonitorWindowsAgent -ExtensionType AzureMonitorWindowsAgent -Publisher Microsoft.Azure.Monitor -ResourceGroupName <RG-Name>-VMName <vmname> -Location "West Europe" -TypeHandlerVersion "1.1" -EnableAutomaticUpgrade $true

Result:


Add the Azure VM to the Data collection rule by following these steps.

Go to Monitor > Data Collection Rules > Create.


Add the VMs to the Data Collection rule on resource tab



Add data sources and destination as below


Destination


Once the complete all the steps the VM is reporting to the log analytics workspaces configured in the DCR as below.


Reference:  Basic troubleshooting steps (installation, agent not running, configuration issues)
